# Generate pydantic model from a dict

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there a straight-forward approach to generate a Pydantic model from a dictionary?

Here is a sample of the data I have.

```
{
    'id': '424c015f-7170-4ac5-8f59-096b83fe5f5806082020',
    'contacts': [{
        'displayName': 'Norma Fisher',
        'id': '544aa395-0e63-4f9a-8cd4-767b3040146d'
    }],
    'startTime': '2020-06-08T09:38:00+00:00'
}
```

Expecting a model similar to ...

```
class NewModel(BaseModel):
    id: str
    contacts: list
    startTime: str
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use `MyModel.parse_obj(my_dict)` to generate a model from a dictionary. According to the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#helper-functions) –

> this is very similar to the `__init__` method of the model, except it takes a dict rather than keyword arguments.

Comment: That wasn't the question.

Comment: @AlexK it was accepted, so it seems to be a good enough answer

Comment: This was deprecated in the recent versions.
`MyModel.model_validate()` is suggested to use instead.

Comment: how to do this when you have nested classes too? the model_validate() is not doing it for me!

Answer (score 49):

You can also use its `__init__` method:

```py
your_mode = YourMode(**your_dict)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#unwrapping-a-dict-and-extra-keywords is doing this: `UserInDB(**user_in.dict(), hashed_password=hashed_password)`. What they term "unwrapping" the dict, then adding any keyword arguments.

Comment: This method works, but makes backwards compatibility more difficult. If you add a new attribute to the JSON but an older version of the model tries to load it with **kwargs when you'll get an error. If you use `Model.parse_obj` instead the extra argument is simply ignored.

Comment: This is about model creation from scratch, not about populating models.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if it were in my hands I would've made the change.:) Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 7):

There's no method for exactly that, but you can use [`create_model()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) to create a model if you know the field types.

Or there's [datamodel-code-generator](https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator) (separate package) which allows you to generate models from schema definitions.

Comment: datamodel-codegen --input file.json --output model.py --input-file-type json

Answer (score 6):

I use this method to generate models at run time using a dictionary definition. This approach allows you to define nested models too. The field type syntax borrows from the create_model method.

```js
from pydantic import create_model
m = {
    "a":(int,...),
    "b":{
        "c":(str,"hi"),
        "d":{
            "e":(bool,True),
            "f":(float,0.5)
        }
    }
}

def dict_model(name:str,dict_def:dict):
    fields = {}
    for field_name,value in dict_def.items():
        if isinstance(value,tuple):
            fields[field_name]=value
        elif isinstance(value,dict):
            fields[field_name]=(dict_model(f'{name}_{field_name}',value),...)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Field {field_name}:{value} has invalid syntax")
    return create_model(name,**fields)

model = dict_model("some_name",m)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but adding on to it is a lot that I have custom crafted, do take a look at the below answer too.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a sample json and want to generate a pydantic model for validation and use it, then you can try this website - https://jsontopydantic.com/
which can generate a pydantic model from a sample json

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I like @data_wiz dictionary definition, Here is an alternative suggestion based on what my needs to take simple JSON responses on the fly which are normally CamelCase key elements and be able to process this into a pythonic styled class.

With the standard functions JSON converts to Dict easily, however!
I wanted to work on this in a pythonic style
I also wanted to be able to have some type overrides converting strings to pythonic types
I also wanted to indicated elements that are optional. This is where I start loving Pydantic.

The following code snippet can generate a model from an actual data Dict from a JSON API response, as keys are camelcase it will convert them to pythonic snake style but retain the CamelCase as Alias.

This pydantic aliasing enables easy consumption of a JSON converted to Dict without key conversion and also the direct export of JSON formatted output. NB observe the config of the dynamic model `DynamicModel.__config__.allow_population_by_field_name = True` this allow the creation of a dynamicModel from Alias or Pythonic field names.

This Code is not fully featured currently cannot handle Lists but it is working well for me for simple cases.
Example of use is in the docstring of the pydanticModelGenerator

```py
from inflection import underscore
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, create_model


class ModelDef(BaseModel):
    """Assistance Class for Pydantic Dynamic Model Generation"""

    field: str
    field_alias: str
    field_type: Any


class pydanticModelGenerator:
    """
    Takes source_data:Dict ( a single instance example of something like a JSON node) and self generates a pythonic data model with Alias to original source field names. This makes it easy to popuate or export to other systems yet handle the data in a pythonic way.
    Being a pydantic datamodel all the richness of pydantic data validation is available and these models can easily be used in FastAPI and or a ORM

    It does not process full JSON data structures but takes simple JSON document with basic elements

    Provide a model_name, an example of JSON data and a dict of type overrides

    Example:

    source_data = {'Name': '48 Rainbow Rd',
        'GroupAddressStyle': 'ThreeLevel',
        'LastModified': '2020-12-21T07:02:51.2400232Z',
        'ProjectStart': '2020-12-03T07:36:03.324856Z',
        'Comment': '',
        'CompletionStatus': 'Editing',
        'LastUsedPuid': '955',
        'Guid': '0c85957b-c2ae-4985-9752-b300ab385b36'}

    source_overrides = {'Guid':{'type':uuid.UUID},
            'LastModified':{'type':datetime },
            'ProjectStart':{'type':datetime },
            }
    source_optionals = {"Comment":True}

    #create Model
    model_Project=pydanticModelGenerator(
        model_name="Project",
        source_data=source_data,
        overrides=source_overrides,
        optionals=source_optionals).generate_model()

    #create instance using DynamicModel
    project_instance=model_Project(**project_info)

    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        model_name: str = None,
        source_data: str = None,
        overrides: Dict = {},
        optionals: Dict = {},
    ):
        def field_type_generator(k, overrides, optionals):
            pass
            field_type = str if not overrides.get(k) else overrides[k]["type"]
            return field_type if not optionals.get(k) else Optional[field_type]

        self._model_name = model_name
        self._json_data = source_data
        self._model_def = [
            ModelDef(
                field=underscore(k),
                field_alias=k,
                field_type=field_type_generator(k, overrides, optionals),
            )
            for k in source_data.keys()
        ]

    def generate_model(self):
        """
        Creates a pydantic BaseModel
        from the json and overrides provided at initialization
        """
        fields = {
            d.field: (d.field_type, Field(alias=d.field_alias)) for d in self._model_def
        }
        DynamicModel = create_model(self._model_name, **fields)
        DynamicModel.__config__.allow_population_by_field_name = True
        return DynamicModel
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a customized code for data model generation using python dicts.

Code mostly borrowed from @data_wiz

#### Helper Functions

```py
from pydantic import create_model
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62267544/generate-pydantic-model-from-a-dict
from copy import deepcopy

def get_default_values(input_schema_copy):
    """Get the default values from the structured schema dictionary. Recursive Traversal of the Schema is performed here.

    Args:
        input_schema_copy (dict): The input structured dictionary schema. Preferred deepcopy of the input schema to avoid inplace changes for the same.

    Returns:
        default_values (dict): The default values of the input schema.

    """    
    for k, v in input_schema_copy.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            input_schema_copy[k] = get_default_values(v)
        else:
            input_schema_copy[k] = v[1]
    return input_schema_copy

def get_defaults(input_schema):
    """Wrapper around get_default_values to get the default values of the input schema using a deepcopy of the same to avoid arbitrary value changes.

    Args:
        input_schema (dict): The input structured dictionary schema.

    Returns:
        default_values (dict): The default values of the input schema.
    """    
    input_schema_copy = deepcopy(input_schema)
    return get_default_values(input_schema_copy)

def are_any_defaults_empty(default_values):
    """Check if any of the default values are empty (Ellipsis - ...)?

    Args:
        default_values (dict): The default values of the input schema.

    Returns:
        Bool: True if any of the default values are empty (Ellipsis - ...), False otherwise.
    """    
    for _, v in default_values.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            are_any_defaults_empty(v)
        else:
            if v is Ellipsis: # ... symbol
                return True
    
    return False

def correct_schema_structure(input_schema_copy):
    for k, v in input_schema_copy.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            input_schema_copy[k] = correct_schema_structure(v)
        elif type(v) == type:
            input_schema_copy[k] = (v,...)
        elif not hasattr(v, '__iter__') or isinstance(v, str):
            input_schema_copy[k] = (type(v),v)
    return input_schema_copy


def dict_model(dict_def:dict, name :str = "Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model"):
    """Helper function to create the Pydantic Model from the dictionary.

    Args:
        name (str): The Model Name that you wish to give to the Pydantic Model.
        dict_def (dict): The Schema Definition using a Dictionary.

    Raises:
        ValueError: When the Schema Definition is not a Tuple/Dictionary.

    Returns:
        pydantic.Model: A Pydantic Model.
    """    
    fields = {}
    for field_name,value in dict_def.items():
        if isinstance(value,tuple):
            fields[field_name]=value
        elif isinstance(value,dict):
            # assign defaults to nested structures here (if present)
            default_value = get_defaults(value)
            default_value = Ellipsis if are_any_defaults_empty(default_value) else default_value
            fields[field_name]=(dict_model(value, f'{name}_{field_name}'),default_value)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Field {field_name}:{value} has invalid syntax")
    print(fields) # helpful for debugging
    return create_model(name,**fields)
```

#### Schema Correction

```py
input_schema = {
    "a":(int,...),
    "b":{
        "c":(str,"hi"),
        "d":{
            "e":(bool,True),
            "f":(float,0.5)
        },
    },
    "g":"hello",
    "h" : 123,
    "i" : str,
    "k" : int
}

input_schema_corrected = correct_schema_structure(input_schema)
input_schema_corrected
```

**Output :**

```
{'a': (int, Ellipsis),
 'b': {'c': (str, 'hi'), 'd': {'e': (bool, True), 'f': (float, 0.5)}},
 'g': (str, 'hello'),
 'h': (int, 123),
 'i': (str, Ellipsis),
 'k': (int, Ellipsis)}
```

#### Actual Model Creation

```py
model = dict_model(dict_def= input_schema, name= "Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model")
```

#### Checking the Model Schema

```py
model.schema()
```

```
{'title': 'Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model',
 'type': 'object',
 'properties': {'a': {'title': 'A', 'type': 'integer'},
  'b': {'title': 'B',
   'default': {'c': 'hi', 'd': {'e': True, 'f': 0.5}},
   'allOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model_b'}]},
  'g': {'title': 'G', 'default': 'hello', 'type': 'string'},
  'h': {'title': 'H', 'default': 123, 'type': 'integer'},
  'i': {'title': 'I', 'type': 'string'},
  'k': {'title': 'K', 'type': 'integer'}},
 'required': ['a', 'i', 'k'],
 'definitions': {'Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model_b_d': {'title': 'Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model_b_d',
   'type': 'object',
   'properties': {'e': {'title': 'E', 'default': True, 'type': 'boolean'},
    'f': {'title': 'F', 'default': 0.5, 'type': 'number'}}},
  'Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model_b': {'title': 'Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model_b',
   'type': 'object',
   'properties': {'c': {'title': 'C', 'default': 'hi', 'type': 'string'},
    'd': {'title': 'D',
     'default': {'e': True, 'f': 0.5},
     'allOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/Demo_Pydantic_Nested_Model_b_d'}]}}}}}
```

#### Validation on Test Data

```py
test_dict = { "a" : 0, "i" : "hello", "k" : 123}

model(**test_dict).dict()
```

Advantages over original answer :

- Extended Default Values (for nested structures)
- Easier Type Declarations

Answer (score 1):

For Pydantic version 2, use the [`model_validate`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_validate) class method inherited from `BaseModel`. The `parse_obj` method is deprecated in pydantic version 2. The [migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#changes-to-pydanticbasemodel) has more information about deprecated methods.

```py
model_instance = NewModel.model_validate(data)
```